WebDav network drive fails in Windows 10
Two computers to setup as WebDav server and client.
On the server:
(1) IIS 10.0 and WebDav Publishing.
(2) I enabled "Basic Authentication" in IIS and disable all the others.
(3) For certificate, I imported a "Trusted Root Cert" (from client computer) and select it in IIS in the website's "Edit Site Binding".
On the client:
(1) In hosts file:
192.168.227.142       dyc.com

(2) Server and client are under the same WIFI hotspot, and client can ping server.
On both server and client sides:
(1) Registry is set below:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
BasicAuthLevel: 1
(2)
All firewalls are turned off.
Current status is:
(1)
On the server, I can map the website to a drive successfully by below command:
net use * https://localhost /p:yes

(2)
On the client, attempt to map the server website by below command fails:
C:\Users\xuejd1>net use * https://dyc.com /p:yes
System error 1790 has occurred.

The network logon failed.


C:\Users\xuejd1>net use * https://dyc.com /p:yes
System error 59 has occurred.

An unexpected network error occurred.

Any advice?

You need to test access to https://dyc.com from the client using a browser, and get a packet capture if it fails.

The client side WebDAV support is officially deprecated by Microsoft,
https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features



Feature
Details and mitigation
Deprecation announced




Webclient (WebDAV) Service
The Webclient (WebDAV) service is deprecated. The Webclient service isn't started by default in Windows. For more information on WebDAV, see WebDAV - Win32 apps.
November 2023



You should move away from WebDAV and consider solutions such as OneDrive, or switch to a third party WebDAV client.
